# Ejecutar avgdude.exe desde Java usando Runtime y ProcessBuilder

Tags: java

Saludos cordiales a todos soy nuevo en la comunidad

Actualmente estoy desarrollando una IDE en java, la cual permitirá realizar grabación de los Chip atmega328 y otros, y estoy implementado una interface grafica para el software avrdude y avr-gcc, estoy intentando simplemente ejecutar la instrucción avrdude.exe con Runtime y ProcessBuilder y con las 2 no se me muestra la ejecución de avrdude.exe, a pesar de que estoy usando InputStream.

Cuando lo ejecuto me da como salida lo siguiente:

*Exited with error code : 0*

Y este es el codigo:

```
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
    processBuilder.command("C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/tools/bin/avrdude.exe");
    try {
        Process process = processBuilder.start();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        String texto1="";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Camp_Text.setText(line);
            texto1+=line+"\n";
        }
        Camp_Text.setText(texto1);
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("\n Exited with error code : " + exitCode);
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
        Camp_Text.setText("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    } 
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Solo_Pruebas1.class.getName()).lo g(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        Camp_Text.setText("Error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

esta es la otra que he realizado

```
    try {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String cmdString = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/tools/bin/avrdude.exe";

        System.out.println(cmdString);
        Process pr = rt.exec(cmdString);

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new BuffutStreamReader(pr.getInputStream()));

        String line = null;

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        int exitVal = pr.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Exited with error code " + exitVal);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```